# Hive Create big table from small tables

Tags: join, apache-spark, hive

I have 1000 tables in hive. All have same columns. These tables will be incrementally updated.The columns are ID, name, dno, loc,sal …..
I want to create a big table by selecting only Id, name and sal from each table.

```
Table 1:
ID name dno loc sal  ………
1  sam  201 HYD 2000 ………

Table2
ID name dno loc sal ………
2  Ram  203 BAN 3000    ………

Table 3
ID name dno loc sal ………
3  Bam  301 NY  4000    ………
```

And So on….

Big table:

```
ID  name sal    
1   sam  2000   
2   Ram  3000
3   Bam  4000
```

And so on

This is what I want to achieve.

Say If there is anew record tomorrow insert into table 3 say with Id 100, name jack ….

Table 3 with new records

```
Table 3
ID  name dno    loc sal ………
3   Bam  301    NY  4000    ………
100 Jack 101    LA  5000    ……….
```

The new big table should be

```
ID  name sal    
1   sam  2000   
2   Ram  3000
3   Bam  4000
100 Jack 5000
```

This is what I want to achieve without deleting the big table every time a new record is being inserted into the original 1000 tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly modified version of ravinder.

Create your child external tables as below.

```
   create external table table1 (
    column1 String,
    Column2 String
    )
    row format delimited                                                                                       
    fields terminated by ','
    LOCATION '/user/cloudera/data_p/table_name=data1/';
```

Now your parent table will be created with a partitioned column table_name.

```
create external table parent_table (
column1 String,
Column2 String
)
partitioned by (table_name String)
row format delimited                                                                                       
fields terminated by ','
LOCATION '/user/cloudera/data_p/';
```

> msck repair table parent_table;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if the ID is unique between all your tables, you can update your big table like

```
with q1 as ( 
select * from T1 where ID not in (select ID from BIGTABLE)
union
select * from T2 where ID not in (select ID from BIGTABLE)    
.... so on
)
from q1
insert into table BIGTABLE select *;
```

if you can find the same ID between different tables (for exampleID=1 in T1 and T4), I would suggest use a extra column in the big table to identify the record source (from what tables it comes) or partition the data (depends on the size of the data). Post a comment if something doesn't make sense

Regards!

EDIT: like I said in the comment, if is not possible do an union for all the tables, I would recommend create a partitioned table. The idea is add a partition to this table pointing to the location of the other tables, in that way you should be able to apply the logic that I wrote before, this is possible to do if you are using avro/parquet format using schema evolution.

Comment: For sample I have 10 tables but If I have more than 1000 tables how would you do it. Doing union on 1000 tables I think is not the correct solution

Comment: if is not possible and all the tables have the same structure, I would recommend create a partitioned table with the same structure of your 1000 tables. The idea is add a partition to this table pointing to the location in the other tables, in that way you should be able to apply the logic that I wrote before, or even better! that table will be your BIGTABLE :)

Comment: I have edited the question properly please have a look and let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can do couple of ways, but I like below if no constraints. make sure all small table location is one directory.

if following does not work,Need more info(criteria of naming for small tables, row formatted of a table )  (other way is to create a script selecting from meta data and get small table name and do a a script with union from small data and insert into big table)

small tables r1 & r2 and big table dept

```
create table r1
(dept int
,dept_name string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/apps/hive/warehouse/dept/r1';

create table r2
(dept int
,dept_name string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/apps/hive/warehouse/dept/r2';


[root@sandbox ~]# hadoop fs -ls -R /apps/hive/warehouse/dept
drwxrwxrwx   - root hdfs          0 2017-01-25 17:43         /apps/hive/warehouse/dept/r1
-rwxrwxrwx   3 root hdfs        105 2017-01-25 17:43     /apps/hive/warehouse/dept/r1/000000_0
-rwxrwxrwx   3 root hdfs          0 2017-01-25 17:43 /apps/hive/warehouse/dept/r1/000001_0
drwxrwxrwx   - root hdfs          0 2017-01-25 17:44 /apps/hive/warehouse/dept/r2
-rwxrwxrwx   3 root hdfs        105 2017-01-25 17:44 /apps/hive/warehouse/dept/r2/000000_0
-rwxrwxrwx   3 root hdfs          0 2017-01-25 17:44 /apps/hive/warehouse/dept/r2/000001_0



create external table dept
(dept int
,dept_name string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/apps/hive/warehouse/dept/';
```

Comment: I recreated the script you have given here but when I do select * from dept. It shows Zero results

Comment: Do you have data in r1 and r2 and also location is simiar as '/apps/hive/warehouse/dept/'